# std::map initialization with a std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I want to initialize a `std::map` object with keys contained in a `std::vector` object.

```
std::vector<char> mykeys { 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
std::map<char, int> myMap;
```

How can I do that without a loop?

And can I add a default value to my `int`?

Comment: Can you use a std library function that uses a loop internally?

Comment: the int value is 0.

Yes I can use a std lib function, but I ask myself if there is an automatic way to construct a map with a vector ?

Comment: what is wrong about the loop ?

Comment: _"without a loop"_ why ? Just want to know how ? Interview stuffs ? Or just wanted to impress your boss/yourself ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Without an *explicit* loop:

```
std::transform( std::begin(mykeys), std::end(mykeys),
                std::inserter(myMap, myMap.end()),
                [] (char c) {return std::make_pair(c, 0);} );
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/051f66036d1247bf).

A range-based for loop would be far more sexy though, so use that if possible:

```
for (auto c : mykeys)
    myMap.emplace(c, 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

**No**, you cannot do that without a loop or equivalent construct. (full stop) You can hide the loop inside some functions, such as `std::transform()`, but not avoid it. Moreover, compilers are well trained to optimize loops (because they are ubiquotous), so there is no good reason to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this without a loop. What you can do is to hide a loop under a standard algorithm because you need to convert an object of type `char` to an object of type `std::map<char, int>::value_type` that represents itself `std::pair<const char, int>`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<char> v { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
    std::map<char, int> m;

    std::transform( v.begin(), v.end(), std::inserter( m, m.begin() ),
        []( char c ){ return std::pair<const char, int>( c, 0 ); } );

    for ( const auto &p : m )
    {
        std::cout << p.first << '\t' << p.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
a   0
b   0
c   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `boost`:

```
template<class Iterators, class Transform>
boost::iterator_range< boost::transform_iterator<
  typename std::decay_t<Transform>::type,
  Iterator
>> make_transform_range( Iterator begin, Iterator end, Transform&& t ) {
  return {
    boost::make_transform_iterator( begin, t ),
    boost::make_transform_iterator( end, t )
  };
}
```

A helper to map keys to pairs:

```
template<class T>
struct key_to_element_t {
  T val;
  template<class K>
  std::pair< typename std::decay<K>::type, T > operator()(K&& k) const {
    return std::make_pair( std::forward<K>(k), val );
  }
};
template<class T>
key_to_element_t< typename std::decay<T>::type > key_to_element( T&& t ) {
  return { std::forward<T>(t) };
}

template<class R>
struct range_to_container_t {
  R r;
  template<class C>
  operator C()&& {
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    return { begin(std::forward<R>(r)), end(std::forward<R>(r)) };
  }
};
template<class R>
range_to_container_t<R> range_to_container( R&& r ) { return std::forward<R>(r); }
```

after all that mess we get:

```
std::vector<char> mykeys { 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
std::map<char, int> myMap = range_to_container( make_transform_range( begin(mykeys), end(mykeys), key_to_element( 0 ) ) );
```

which constructs the `std::map` directly from a transformed sequence of elements in the `mykeys` vector.

Pretty silly.